# Unconventional code in JDK - specific constructions used for unknown reason

Tags: java, optimization, bytecode

I was looking through JDK (JDK 12, but it applies to older ones too) code and found some weird constructions, and I don't understand why they were used. Let's take for example `Map.computeIfPresent`, since it's simple:

```java
default V computeIfPresent(K key, BiFunction<? super K, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    Object oldValue;
    if ((oldValue = this.get(key)) != null) {
        V newValue = remappingFunction.apply(key, oldValue);
        if (newValue != null) {
            this.put(key, newValue);
            return newValue;
        } else {
            this.remove(key);
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This construction `if ((oldValue = this.get(key)) != null)` surprised me. I knew it's possible, because it's nothing really special, but in normal production code I would consider it a code smell. Why not just write it in a normal way (`Object oldValue = this.get(key)`)? Must be some clutch optimization, that's what I thought.

Wrote a smaller version to check the bytecode:

```java
int computeIfPresent(int key) {
  Integer oldValue;
  if ((oldValue = get(key)) != null) {
    return oldValue;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Bytecode output:

```
int computeIfPresent(int);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iload_1
     2: invokevirtual #2                  // Method get:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     5: dup
     6: astore_2
     7: ifnull        15
    10: aload_2
    11: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
    14: ireturn
    15: iconst_2
    16: ireturn
```

Bytecode for 'normal' version with classic variable initialization:

```
int computeIfPresent(int);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: iload_1
     2: invokevirtual #2                  // Method get:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
     5: astore_2
     6: aload_2
     7: ifnull        15
    10: aload_2
    11: invokevirtual #3                  // Method java/lang/Integer.intValue:()I
    14: ireturn
    15: iconst_2
    16: ireturn
```

The only difference is `dup + astore_2` vs `astore_2 + aload_2`. I could even suspect that the first 'clutch-optimized' version is worse, because `dup` is used and stack is bigger for no reason. Maybe my example was too simple and optimization scales a lot in more complicated context.

And this is a simple example and definitely not a single occurrence in JDK code - open `HashMap.java`, there is tons of fragments like this, sometimes multiple on the same line:

`if ((first = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) != null)`

Even though it's really simple I have to stop for a moment and think what this code actually does, because of those constructions.

What is the real reason behind using those constructions? I'm sure it's not just bad code. In my opinion code quality suffers a lot, so the benefit must be substantial. Or just the rule `leave small optimizations to JIT` does not apply to JDK, because it must squeeze as much performance as possible?

Or is this just going extreme with rule `initialize variables as late as possible`?:)

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is just a matter of coding style, i.e personal preference on the part of the Java devs. There's no great performance secret behind it.

Comment: I would say it's probably nothing to do with performance, but rather that it's done this way to highlight the fact that the _only_ use for `oldValue` is inside the `if` block. If it was initialized on the declaration statement, it will have a value after the closing bracket of the `else` block and the reader would have to visually scan past the whole `if/else` construct to see that `oldValue` is not used anywhere else.

Comment: To me, this does not look "unconventional" at all. Assignments as expressions are part of the core Java language and are commonly used in all sorts of Java programs. Personally, I have never spent a moment thinking about performance of its use. I use it if and when it makes the code easier to read. Specifically, I regularily do reading an InputStream to the end like `while( (cnt = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) { // process cnt bytes from buffer...}`. Much better than putting one `read` before the loop and another one at the end of the loop's body, IMHO.

Comment: @JimmyB another example: `if(foo != null && (bar = foo.getBar()) != null) { /* use bar */ }`. However, it’s still not needed in the question’s example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the JVM specification, specifically in exactly the difference you pointed out: the `dup` instruction ([JVMS §6.5.dup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dup)). From those docs:

> Duplicate the top value on the operand stack and push the duplicated value onto the operand stack.

Looking at the operand stack documentation ([JVMS §2.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2), **emphasis** added):

> A small number of Java Virtual Machine instructions (the `dup` instructions (§dup) and `swap` (§swap)) operate on **run-time data areas as raw values without regard to their specific types**; these instructions are defined in such a way that they cannot be used to modify or break up individual values. These restrictions on operand stack manipulation are **enforced through class file verification** (§4.10).

Following that one more level deep and looking at the class verification section ([JVMS §4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10), **emphasis** added):

> Link-time verification enhances the performance of the run-time interpreter. **Expensive checks** that would otherwise have to be performed to verify constraints at run time for **each interpreted instruction** can be **eliminated**. The Java Virtual Machine can **assume that these checks have already been performed**.

This shows that these restrictions are validated at *link* time, which is when the JVM loads your class file. So to answer your question:

> What is the real reason behind using those constructions?

Let's dissect what the instructions do in each case:

In the first case (with the `dup` instruction):

1. `invokevirtual` stores the result at the top of the operand stack
2. `dup` duplicates that so now there are two copies of the result on the top of the stack
3. `astore_2` stores that into local variable #2, which pops one reference off the operand stack
4. `ifnull` checks if the top of the operand stack is null, and if so, goes to instruction 15, otherwise continues (we'll assume it's not null)
5. `aload_2` pushes local variable #2 onto the top of operand stack
6. `invokevirtual` calls a method on the top value of the operand stack, pops it, then pushes the result
7. `ireturn` pops the top value off the operand stack and returns it

In the second case:

1. `invokevirtual` stores the result at the top of the operand stack
2. `astore_2` pops the result off the operand stack and stores it in local variable #2
3. `aload_2` pushes local variable #2 onto the top of operand stack
4. `ifnull` checks if the top of the operand stack is null, and if so, goes to instruction 15, otherwise continues (we'll assume it's not null)
5. `aload_2` pushes local variable #2 onto the top of operand stack
6. `invokevirtual` calls a method on the top value of the operand stack, pops it, then pushes the result
7. `ireturn` pops the top value off the operand stack and returns it

**So what's the difference?** The first one calls `aload_2` once and `dup` once, the second just calls `aload` twice. The difference here will be practically nothing. If you look at the size of the stack throughout the operations, you'll see that the first implementation grows the operand stack by one extra value (less than 10 bytes, usually 8 or 4 bytes depending on 64-bit or 32-bit JVM), but has one less local-variable load from stack memory. The second one keeps the operand stack slightly smaller, but has one extra local-variable load (read: fetch from memory).

At the end of the day, these optimizations will have a **very** minimal impact except in applications with extremely low memory, e.g. embedded systems. So for you? **Do what's readable.**

When in doubt: ["Premature optimization (can be) the root of all evil."](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil) Until you know that your code is slow or can prove that it's slow before running it, you're better off writing code that's readable. This hardly falls into the critical 3% of what you should optimize ahead of time.

Comment: When there are more than four local variables (including `this` and parameters) and the affected variable has an index higher than four, `dup` will save one byte over `aload n` in the compiled code. Still not a big advantage…